# React native var on stylesheer

Tags: react-native

Is It possible to ad a global variable on a stylesheet
Something like this :

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  bigblue: {
    color: 'blue',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: ´$myglobalvar’
  },
  red: {
    color: 'red'
  },
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible and a recommended pattern to have a consistent design in your app.

1. You can define your variable inside your file where your stylesheet is in like this:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
StyleSheet,
Text
} from 'react-native';

const defaultFontSize = 16;

class MyTextComponent extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <Text style={styles.bigblue}>Test</Text>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  bigblue: {
    color: 'blue',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: defaultFontSize
  }
});
```

2. You can use a central file to set your constants like this:

DesignConstants.js

```js
const DesignConstants = {
  "DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE": 16
}

module.exports = DesignConstants;
```

MyTextComponent.js

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
StyleSheet,
Text
} from 'react-native';
import DesignConstants from './DesignConstants'

class MyTextComponent extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <Text style={styles.bigblue}>Test</Text>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  bigblue: {
    color: 'blue',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: DesignConstants.DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE
  }
});
```

If your app gets bigger, I would definitely recommend the second possibility.